# D/InputConnectionAdaptor( 5956): The input method toggled cursor monitoring on

Tags: flutter, navigation, android-emulator, obs, flutter-routes

When I start the application on the Android emulator and try to use the virtual keybord, it immediately gets closed and I see the following message on DEBUG CONSOLE:

```
D/InputConnectionAdaptor( 5956): The input method toggled cursor monitoring on
```

It seems the app gets restarted whenever I try to open the keyboard, because I see messages like below:

```
I/flutter ( 5956): isAuth is false and we are in authentication page
D/InputConnectionAdaptor( 5956): The input method toggled cursor monitoring on
2
I/flutter ( 5956): isAuth is false and we are in authentication page
D/InputConnectionAdaptor( 5956): The input method toggled cursor monitoring on
2
I/flutter ( 5956): isAuth is false and we are in authentication page
```

This is my `main.dart` file and let me know if you think it helps if I put more code:

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Get.put(MenuController());
  Get.put(NavigationController());
  Get.put(AuthController());
  Get.put(AuthCard);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AuthController.instance.tryAutoLogin();
    return GetMaterialApp(
      // initialRoute: AuthController.instance.isAuth
      //     ? rootRoute
      //     : authenticationScreenRoute,
      unknownRoute: GetPage(
          name: '/not-found',
          page: () => PageNotFound(),
          transition: Transition.fadeIn),
      getPages: [
        GetPage(
            name: rootRoute,
            page: () {
              return SiteLayout();
            }),
        GetPage(
            name: authenticationScreenRoute,
            page: () => const AuthenticationScreen()),
        GetPage(name: homeScreenRoute, page: () => const HomeScreen()),
      ],
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'BasicCode',
      theme: ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: light,
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.mulishTextTheme(Theme.of(context).textTheme)
            .apply(bodyColor: Colors.black),
        pageTransitionsTheme: const PageTransitionsTheme(builders: {
          TargetPlatform.iOS: FadeUpwardsPageTransitionsBuilder(),
          TargetPlatform.android: FadeUpwardsPageTransitionsBuilder(),
        }),
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      // home: AuthController.instance.isAuth
      home: Obx(()=>
      AuthController.instance.isAuth
            ? SiteLayout()
            : const AuthenticationScreen(),
       ),
    );
  }
}
```

I also tried to use my Android phone and I got the same error and behavior.

Comment: I am also having the same issue... is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

for me the solution was

```
   autofocus: true,
```